# SQL Server CE 3.5 duplicate rows

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

Been doing some research on finding a solution to my problem with little luck!

Is there a SQL keyword which allows me to easily remove duplicate rows from a table (SQL Server CE compatible)?

If not could any of you guys possibly know any resources which can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new table with the same column
2. Add unique index to columns that you want to make unique (prevent duplicate)
3. Copy records over row by row, ignore any error
4. Empty the original table and copy back the records; or drop old table and rename the new one to old

Comment: Thanks for your input will give it a shot and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Are statements like

```
select distinct x from t
```

not supported? I believe SQL Server CE 3.5 does support DISTINCT statement.

Comment: DISTINCT IS Supported... just somewhat limited.  For example you can't use it inside of a count.  i.e. `count(distinct mydata)`.  But for this scenario it should work fine.

Comment: 'SELECT DISTINCT dir_FileName, dir_ID, dir_Path, dir_Icon
FROM            directories' <b>can you see where im going wrong here